# Set Membership and Set Definition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

Correct me if I am wrong, but I have a strong suspicion that the following two expressions are true. Again, this is only a suspicion. If somebody can point me wrong or right I will be satisfied. And sorry if the question is dumb.

\begin{equation}
a \in X \quad \text{ iff } \quad \exists x : (x \in X) \land (a = x) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $X$ is a finite set and $a$ a urelement.

\begin{equation}
\{x \mid x \in X \;\; \land \;\; P(x) \} \quad = \quad \{ x \mid \forall x \in X: P(x) \} \tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $X$ is a finite set and $P$ is a predicate with argument $x$.

Comment: "non-set elements." -- What do you mean by this?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer That they are not sets. I thought if there is the possibility something would break.

Comment: There is a term **urelement** that describes $a$ and $x$ you want.

Comment: I could not find any reason why two sets in (2) are the same. The conditional in the right-hand-side does not have $x$ as a free variable, so it is empty (if the conditional is false) or the collection of all sets (if the conditional is true.)

Comment: @HanulJeon Now that you point it out I also think that there is something wrong with the RHS of (2). I could not help but to think in the LHS of (2) as somthing related to the universal quantifier.

Comment: I do not agree that the LHS is related to universal quantifiers.

Comment: @HanulJeon I already acknowledged that there is something wrong.

Comment: Sorry, there is a misunderstanding on your comment.

Comment: Of course $(1)$ is always true, it doesn't even depend on the nature of $a$. It's just a basic property of equality.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a set $A$ as 
\begin{align}
 A = \{x \mid Q(x)\}
\end{align}
you mean that, for *every* $z$ in your domain (possibly the universe if you are in naïve set theory), $z \in A$ if and only if $Q(z)$ holds, where $Q(z)$ is obtained from $Q(x)$ by replacing the *free* occurrences of $x$ with $z$.

Now, let $A = \{x \mid \forall x \in X : P(x)\}$ (the set on the right-hand side of identity $(2)$ in your question). This means that, for *every* $z$ in your domain, $z \in A$ if and only if $\forall x (x \in X \to P(x))$ holds ($z$ does not occur here because there is no *free* occurrence of $x$ where $z$ can substitute for it).
Therefore, $A$ is either the empty set (if $\forall x (x \in X \to P(x))$ is false) or the whole domain (if $\forall x (x \in X \to P(x))$ is true).

Clearly, the set $\{x \mid x \in X \land P(x)\}$ (the set on the left-hand side of identity $(2)$ in your question) can be different from the empty set and the whole domain. For instance, think of $X$ as the set of natural numbers and of $P(x)$ as "$x$ is even": in this case, $\{x \mid x \in X \land P(x)\}$ is the set of even natural numbers, in the domain of natural numbers.

So, your identity $(2)$ is wrong, it does not hold because it identifies two sets that are different in general. To make it true, you should remove the universal quantifier $\forall$ (because it binds the occurrences of $x$) from the set $\{x \mid \forall x \in X :P(x)\}$ in $(2)$.
In this way, we set $A = \{x \mid x \in X \land P(x)\}$ and hence, for *every* $z$ in your domain, 
\begin{align}
z \in A \ \text{  if and only if } \ z \in X \land P(z).
\end{align}

---

Independently of from above, your equivalence $(1)$ is always true. More in general, for every property $P(x)$ (in your equivalence $(1)$, $P(x)$ is $x \in X$), the following holds:
\begin{align}
P(a) \ \text{ if and only if } \ \exists x \, (P(x) \land a = x).
\end{align}

Comment: I think you mixed up “left” and “right”. Which of course doesn't take away anything from the argumentation.

Comment: @celtschk - Thank you, fixed.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Could you give me a reference or tell me where I can find more information about the formula you listed above regarding (1).

Comment: @gioOsh - Which formula do you refer to?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco The last formula regarding "P(a) iff there exists P(x) and a=x".